# Consuming php web services with WPF client

Tags: php, .net, web-services, rest

I have created a php RESTful service which respond with data in JSON format and i can easily access it with my android app, but the problem is with my WPF desktop client. Actually, i don't know a better way to call a php web service from a WPF client. Please suggest some good solutions to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue doesn't have anything to do with WPF, but simply .NET in general. You're looking for [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The learning curve is a little steep, but once you've got it set up right, consuming your service in .NET should be pretty simple.